# Регулярное выражение для числа кроме 0

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение, которое дает ввод только цифр от 0 до 9 `/[^0-9]/g` .

Нужно, чтобы ввод был любых чисел, кроме 0, то есть 10,20 - можно, именно 0 один - нельзя.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону смотреть, чтобы сделать подобное?

Comment: В какой момент происходит проверка, при событии keydown? Или при сабмите формы?

Comment: происходит по keydown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если происходит обработка по `keypress`:

```js
var field = document.getElementById('field');

field.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  var
    char = String.fromCharCode(e.which),
    valLen = field.value.length;

  if (char !== '' & !char.match(/[0-9]/) || char === '0' & valLen === 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="field" />
```

Comment: Удалить символ, переместить курсор тоже нельзя ;)

Comment: Не работает. Вводишь `10`, перемещаешь курсор влево, удаляешь `1`, остаётся `0`.

Comment: @Qwertiy. как у вас удаление и перемещение курсора работает? В FF40 только цифры набирать можно, даже `Tab` не переводит курсор на другой элемент.

Comment: @Visman, да. Яндекс-браузер 43.0.2357.2877 x32.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Извиняюсь, исправил пример.

Answer (score 2):

Видимо, Вам нужно где то такое выражение

```
/^[1-9][0-9]*$/
```

Answer (score 2):

Решение только средствами `html`

```html
<input type="text" pattern="[1-9]\d*" required placeholder="Введите число > 0" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Введите текст" />
```

Comment: Ваша регулярка запрещает отрицательные числа

Comment: @AntonioK, автор вопроса ведет речь только про цифры, то есть положительные числа. Посмотрите на все 4 ответа и найдите хоть в одном знак `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Любое положительное целое число без начальных нулей:

```
^[1-9]\d*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно разрешить лидирующие нули, то так:

```
/^(?!0*$)\d*$/
```